# access req.session where request is not available(example: socket on connect)

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I need to access the req.session.user._id for the function where socket.io detects when user is connected. something like the following code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
 console.log('a user connected with the id of: '+req.session.uder._id);
})
```

the reason that I need to access the id in my io.on('connect') is to tell the users who are chatting with this user, that he is online or offline.
so if he is online and authenticated we would do something like this:

```
io.emit("status:"+req.session.user._id, 'online');
```

then other users who arelistening to the status of this user, know his status.

what is the right way to do this?
should I access it in io.on('connect')? or should I do it some other way?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This module will help https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport.socketio
It allows to use the same session storage for expressjs and socket.io

The user authorized will be available by https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport.socketio#socketrequestuser-as-of-v1

Comment: thanks but I'm not using passport I just want to access my sessions